# "Unexpected token } in JSON at position 139" error message

Tags: arrays, json, angular, subscription, angular5

Some problems happened when I run some angular code like this:

> return this.http.get('apiurl').map(res => res as Article[]);

When I checked my cloudwatch, I found my logs look like this:

```
    { Items: 
[ { text: [Object],
    description: [Object],
    id: [Object],
    userid: [Object],
    title: [Object] },
    { text: [Object],
    description: [Object],
    id: [Object],
    userid: [Object],
    title: [Object] },
    { text: [Object],
    description: [Object],
    id: [Object],
    userid: [Object],
    title: [Object] } ],
    Count: 3,
    ScannedCount: 3 }
```

I guess this means I can fetch data from DynamoDB, but error messages showed on my page:

> "Unexpected token } in JSON at position 139"
>   [image]

**I can get my data on codepen without any errors.**
I checked a lot, still could not figure out what went wrong. Could anyone help me with this problem? Any reply will be obliged

Service Code

```
 getArticleById(id:string){
        this.dataLoaded.next(null);
        this.dataLoadFailed.next(false);
       return this.http.get('https://example.com/'+id)
           .map(res => res as Article[]);
    }
```

Called service on some other page:

```
articles:Article[] = [];

getAllArticles(){
    this.articleService.getArticleById('all')
        .subscribe((articles:Article[])=>{
      this.articles = articles;
    })
  }
```

This is the data I got through codepen:

```
[
 {
  "title" : "fakfjdkfjdskaf",
  "description" : "fdkalfjdskalfj",
  "text" : "<p>dkalfjdsklafjdksalfjsda</p><p><br></p>",
  "userid" : "100",
  "id" : "13",
} 
, {
  "title" : "title",
  "description" : "desc",
  "text" : "aaaaa",
  "userid" : "userid",
  "id" : "100",
} 
, {
  "title" : "tiel",
  "description" : "desc",
  "text" : "text",
  "userid" : "di",
  "id" : "12",
} 
]
```

Comment: Can you put actual json string and other code where you get the error?

Comment: Looks like the JSON returned by your http call probbably has an issue. Can you put the JSON as well?

Comment: try with (res => res.json() as Article[]);

Comment: @GaurangDave I added my code and my data,please check it our

Comment: [JSON objects ***can't*** have a trailing comma](http://www.json.org/): so that's *not valid JSON*. Use a JSON-aware editor (not a JavaScript-editor!) or a JSON validator (ie. see any one of the free online JSON validation sites) - that is, there are existing tools/resources to help pinpoint the error in the data, use them!

Comment: @ShrutiNair That will throw an error "Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'." during compiling

Comment: @Ben check my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your json string is wrong. it has extra comma(,) at last element.

Correct json

```
[
 {
  "title" : "fakfjdkfjdskaf",
  "description" : "fdkalfjdskalfj",
  "text" : "<p>dkalfjdsklafjdksalfjsda</p><p><br></p>",
  "userid" : "100",
  "id" : "13"
},
{
  "title" : "title",
  "description" : "desc",
  "text" : "aaaaa",
  "userid" : "userid",
  "id" : "100"
} 
, {
  "title" : "tiel",
  "description" : "desc",
  "text" : "text",
  "userid" : "di",
  "id" : "12"
} 
]
```

Comment: Thank you, THAT is the problem!

Comment: You are welocome Ben